# Python Error while installing QSpatiaLite in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis-plugins, qspatialite

I'd like to install QSpatiaLite to my QGIS2.0 but the following error massage occured while installing with the pluginmanager:

```
Couldn't load plugin QspatiaLite due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/QspatiaLite/__init__.py", line 24, in classFactory
    from qspatialite import QspatiaLite
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/QspatiaLite/qspatialite.py", line 29, in 
    from QspatiaLiteApp import QspatiaLiteApp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/QspatiaLite/QspatiaLiteApp.py", line 27, in 
    from Classes.Database import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/QspatiaLite/Classes/Database.py", line 1, in 
    from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite #Load PySpatiaLite
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from pyspatialite._spatialite import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: libspatialite.so.5: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Python version:
2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:52:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, exported

Python path: ['/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing', '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python', '/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/home/map-pc/.qgis2/python/plugins/DigitizingTools/tools', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you haven't `libspatialite.so` installed.

Please, try the below command prior to install the QSpatiaLite plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install libspatialite-dev
```

Reference:

[Building_GDAL_on_Linux](http://wiki.wildsong.biz/index.php/Building_GDAL_on_Linux)

Comment: Related: If it is installed but not in a standard path, possibly you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar.

Comment: @Sorin The link to `Building_GDAL_on_Linux' seems to be broken.